# Error retrieving value of a column from data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am filling two tables in DataSet.while retrieving column from 2nd table in dataset i am getting error.Please help!

> "There is no row at position 0."

Here is my code.

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spDispatchDetails]
(
@JobNo int,
@Programme nvarchar(100)
)
as

begin

select ReceivedFrom,ChallanNo,ChallanDate,JobNo,ReceivingDate,LotNo from tblOrders where JobNo=@JobNo and OrderStatus='In Process'
select Quantity from tblProgramme where JobNo=@JobNo and Programme=@Programme
end
```

I am sharing image of my code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the row count before accessing the row value of the table...

Comment: There is only one row .sir

Comment: Please, try to include all relevant code in the question, not in screen-shots.

Answer (score 0):

probably it does not return any rows

you need to check the rows count in `ds.Table[1]` before you access rows in it.

Make sure that `ds.Table[1].Rows.Count > 0`

Comment: It is returning because i executed that stored procedure.That is returning only single row from that second table.

Comment: put a breakpoinf and check if ds.Table[1].Rows.Count > 0

Answer (score 0):

> The is no row at position 0

This issue means that there is no row that was returned from the execution of the **SQL** query for the second table in the dataset. For example, the `Quantity` value does not exist if the `tblProgramme` table where the `JobNo` and `Programme` match that values passed into the call.

One of the issues with `ADO.NET` is the amount of effort involved with checking types and row counts, etc.

To solve the issue you should check to ensure that the Table exists and that the Row count is at least 1, and even that the column exists too.

```
if (ds.Tables.Count == 2 && // Ensure two tables in the dataset
    ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0 && // Ensure second table has a row
    ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Quantity"] != DBNull.Value) // Ensure value for Qty
{
    // Then do something with it...
}
```

As a side note, I would suggest using an **ORM** as it removes nearly all of the issues that raw `ADO.NET` boilerplate code introduces.

Answer (score 0):

First check if SQL is returning rows, try executing the query manually.  While debugging make sure the parameters are being sent correctly (the dropdown selected values)

The error is telling you that there is no rows in the second table.  Ideally always check that the row count is greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

On the beginning You should check if Your procedure returns any rows to `ds.Tables[1]`, because this error is very typical to this situation.

Please check this part of Your procedure:

```
select Quantity from tblProgramme where JobNo=@JobNo and Programme=@Programme
```

and let us know if You get any rows.